# baalei teshuva yeshivas in NYC or Miami area?

Tags: yeshiva-school

I'm a recent baalei teshuva in Israel but have to leave to find work as my savings are running low.

Can anyone name any yeshivot geared towards baalei teshuva in the Miami or NYC area?  So far I know Shor Yoshuv and Hadar Hatorah in NYC, and in Miami I know Torah Ohr.  Are there any others?  Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Ohr Somayach in Monsey has a BT program https://ohr.edu/web/branches/monsey.htm

Comment: In Monsey you also have https://torasdovid.org/. Lots of hatzluch in finding a please to learn.